# Handling missing values for association rules using Weka

Tags: data-mining, weka, apriori

I'm new to Weka and stuck with a problem. I have a dataset with about 13 features (all binary). Some of the features are applicable only for a small set of data. When I run association rule mining using Weka, it identifies strong co-relations between attributes based on the feature value being 0 (0 implies the feature does not apply).

I would like the co-relation to be identified only for positive features. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be default behavior, IMHO.

In typical APRIORI use cases, most items are missing from most transactions.

Maybe convert your items to a non-numeric type and subsitute 0 for *missing value*?
The classic example uses this format:

```
@relation supermarket
@attribute 'department1' { t}
...
@data
?,?,...,t,...
```

where `?` indicates missing, `t` indicates presence.